# How to create All Day Calendar Event 14 days from now

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create an all-day calendar event to 14 days from today using Google App Script but I keep getting the error

> Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent.

My script is:

```
  var SheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var SelectedRow = SheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var value = SheetApp.getRange(SelectedRow, 8).getValue(); //Name of the event

  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("sampleemail@gmail.com");
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent(value.toString(), new Date() + 14);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a number to a Date object, the Date is automatically converted to its underlying value, i.e., the number of milliseconds since the [epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The result of the addition will be that number of *milliseconds*  plus 14, which is just a big integer. The `createAllDayEvent()` method expects a Date object rather than an integer.

To get a date that is 14 *days* from now, use [Date.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate). This method has the benefit that it automatically takes care of rolling into the next month or next year as necessary, but be careful. The `setDate()` method modifies a Date object in place, but does not *return* the Date object. Instead, it returns the underlying value, i.e., the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

This means that you cannot just assign the result you get from `setDate()` to a variable in the hope of getting a valid Date. Something like `const twoWeeksFromNow = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 14)` will not work if you expect `twoWeeksFromNow` to contain a Date.

An easy way to get it right is to use a short utility function, like this:

```
function testCreateAllDayEvent() {
  const twoWeeksFromNow = dateOffset_(new Date(), +14);
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("sample_email@gmail.com");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const eventTitle = sheet
    .getRange('H' + sheet.getActiveRange().getRow())
    .getDisplayValue();
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, twoWeeksFromNow);
}

/**
* Gets a new Date object that is offset by numDays from date.
*
* @param {Date} date The date from which to count.
* @param {Number} numDays The number of days to add or subtract from date.
* @return {Date} A new Date object that is offset by numDays from date.
*/
function dateOffset_(date, numDays) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + numDays);
  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, while waiting for help, I tried a couple of things and got it to work with the below. Same as suggested here, I should have checked back here first lol

    const DateToday = new Date();
    DateToday.setDate(DateToday.getDate() + 14);

Answer (score 0):

Change second parameter

```
new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 14)
```